# Close to the metal C++ Palindrome Program

Tags: c++, performance, palindrome

I am attempting to reinvent the wheel by writing my own palindrome checking program in C++, using only basic loops and mathematical operations. I have arrived at a solution, but was wondering if it's the best solution and if it could be improved. I'm doing this primarily as a learning exercise. My code:

```
#include <iostream> // cout
#include <stdio.h>  // printf
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool is_palidrome(string inputString) {
  int num_to_parse = inputString.size();

  /* immediately return on single letter string as all single letter strings are palindromes -- saves CPU time as programme does not need to enter the loop */
  if(num_to_parse == 1) {
      return true;
  }

  for(int i=0; num_to_parse; i++) {
      int point_end = num_to_parse - i - 1;
    if(inputString[i] == inputString[point_end]) {
      continue;
    } else if (i == num_to_parse) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}}


int main() {
    // Change the value of inputString to test different palindromes
    string inputString = "caabaac";
    printf("%s", is_palidrome(inputString)?"This is a palindrome.":"Not a palindrome."); // ternary: test condition ? return this if true : return this if false
    return 0;
}
```

I think at the moment I'm doing about 2x the number of loops I need to do, and so wasting CPU time. Also, there may be further optimizations. Any help really appreciated as I really want to understand this stuff properly and contribute to code-bases, rather than just doing everything with other people's higher-level code.

Comment: I realize this is a small program, but you should still check this out;

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: what exactly is close to the metal here?

Comment: When you are up to a task you are supposed to analyse what you have at hand before writing the code. A palindrome is a word that is mirrored across its middle, who could even think about checking all the chars in it? Remove the for, declare two indexes (two int), set one to 0, the other one to the end of the string, and while-loop 'till the first index is greater or equal than the second one (remember to ++ and -- the indexes inside the loop, obviously)

Comment: What exactly is your definition of palindrome? Many traditional english palindromes will not be detected by your solution. For example: - Madam I'm Adam - Able was I ere I saw Elba - A man, a plan, a canal, Panama! Does your solution consider languages other than English? - Japanese: かるいきびんなこねこなんびきいるか - Chinese: 上海自来水来自海上 - Hindi: नवजीवन Does it consider accent folding? - Spanish: Adán no cede con nada.

Comment: If you're going to say "close to the metal", make sure your code is in assembly, not a high-level language.

Comment: Perhaps they just mean they're not going to run their code in a virtual machine.

Comment: Using tail-rec, a "oneliner" solution: `template<typename It> bool isPalindrome(It begin, It end) { return end - begin <=1 ||  (*begin == *(end-1) && isPalindrome(begin+1, end-1)); }`. [Works for `std::string`, `std::array`, `std::vector`, native arrays...](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cacd8003eb3fc360).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; num_to_parse; i++)
```

wut

Why is `num_to_parse` your condition? Then you have `if (i == num_to_parse)` in there, too? That's odd. I'd rewrite this as:

```
for(int i=0; i < num_to_parse; i++) {
  int point_end = num_to_parse - i - 1;
  if(inputString[i] == inputString[point_end]) {
    continue;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
return true;
```

---

If you want to simplify that even further, you can just do this:

```
for(int i=0; i <= num_to_parse; i++) {
  int point_end = num_to_parse - i - 1;
  if(inputString[i] != inputString[point_end]) {

    return false;
  }
}
return true;
```

Take note of the different condition. There are a couple of other simplifying improvements, but they're mentioned in [another answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/161506/62850).

---

While I was writing that, I realized that your indentation is... odd, to say the least. Please don't use things like `}}` in code; while there are a few rare cases where it might be OK (nested namespaces that, as is typical, you didn't indent), none of them apply here.

---

[`using namespace std` is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1863564). Please don't do it.

---

```
printf("%s", is_palidrome(inputString)?"This is a palindrome.":"Not a palindrome.");
```

This is just... weird. I mean, first of all, you don't have a trailing newline, so it might never output anything at all. In my C IDE, for example, it would, but on my Bash console, it'd definitely look odd (`This is a palindrome.q@my-hostname ~>`), if it prints at all. Even ignoring that inconsistency... why do it like that? The ternary just makes it more complicated than it has to be.

If you insist on using C functions (more on that later), do this:

```
if (is_palindrome(inputString)) {
  puts("This is a palindrome.");
} else {
  puts("Not a palindrome.");
}
```

The C++ equivalent should be fairly straightforward; replace the `puts(...)` with `std::cout << ... << "\n";`, or `std::endl` in place of `"\n"` if you want to be paranoid about flushing every single line instead of just ensuring that it's flushed in a few key places (which is what I do in performance-critical stuff, because writing to the console is *slow*, and until you tell them to, most C++ standard libraries will avoid doing it for as long as is reasonable)

---

Now to talk about that "using C functions" thing. Why are you doing it at all? You have *all of C++'s power* to bring to bear, but you don't. If you want to write this in C, write it in C -- it'd only be changing, like four lines. Maybe less. Don't use just a tiny part of C++. Or, alternatively, just write C.

---

With regards to your original concern about speed, you're doing this in O(n) (as far as I can tell), which is the absolute lower limit. You're still iterating over every character, though, so it's not as fast as it could get -- you only need to iterate over half.

---

Finally, what do you mean by "close to the metal"? This is just C with a tiny sprinkling of C++, which are both high-level languages. Not as high-level as, say, Python, but the definition of a high-level language is that it's abstracted from any one particular machine, which C and C++ are. There's nothing close to the metal here. That would be machine code, or maybe Assembly.

Comment: Wow, it's strange it works in any coding environment with that error in there! No-wonder I was seeing divergent behaviour in different environments!

Comment: ...In the time it took me to finish my review after I forgot that Tab moves to the next thing, rather than indenting, I got 2 upvotes and an accept. Thanks? :D

Comment: @RailsKiddie That's not the only one -- see my edit. There's one other thing that'd make it behave inconsistently, at least that I saw.

Comment: I'll have a proper read through. This is all really useful. Obviously if I'd known the code wouldn't work in all environments when posting I'd have posted in SO, not here, but as it is I'm very pleased with the feedback and this is a really useful response.

Comment: *"Please don't use things like `}}` in code, ever, for any reason"*  What about when you're closing two nested namespaces, and you haven't indented because no one indents code inside a namespace block? Never say never. :-) To be fair, I guess I'd write `} }  // namespace foo::bar`, but still looks suspiciously close to what you've issued a blanket ban on.

Comment: @CodyGray OK, fair enough. I was thinking in terms of C, because this program is basically just C, and C doesn't have (user-specifiable) namespaces.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Yeah, with the stuff I'm doing with the strings I might as well have just declared them as arrays of chars.

Comment: @CodyGray I prefer `} // namespace foo::bar` and then on the next line `} // namespace foo`.  Unless you have heavily nested namespace hierarchies (why?) it's not that much extra work, and this makes it much easier to read (IMO) and allows you to add things to `foo` easily if need be.  Or if you don't need to support old compilers, just use C++17's `namespace foo::bar {  }`.

Comment: @bcrist Something I'm working on reminded me of your comment. I'm making a pretty big, complicated project with a big, complicated codebase, but the simplest API I could figure out. The whole thing is, in itself, just one part of a still-larger project (a game engine), so I end up writing classes in `engine::physics::collision`. Unfortunately, I'm stuck in C++11, because there's some code I'm depending on and can't port, so I end up uysing `namespace engine { namespace physics { namespace collision {` at the top of the file, then `} } }` at the bottom, usually with a `// close namespaces`.

Answer (score 28):

First thing: this [doesn't work](https://ideone.com/GsWgkZ)

---

```
#include <iostream> // cout
#include <stdio.h>  // printf
#include <string>
```

You included `<iostream>`, but didn't use it in favour of `printf`. If we actually use `<iostream>` as is the C++ way, then `<stdio.h>` isn't needed.

---

```
using namespace std;
```

For small examples and programs, this isn't much of a issue; but in bigger programs, using the `std` namespace at the top level of a file pollutes the global namespace, which is especially terrible if used in a header file.

---

```
    int num_to_parse = inputString.size();
```

`auto` should be used here instead of `int`, for correctness and in case the input string is ever *really* large and overflows the maximum limit of `int`.

---

```
    if (num_to_parse == 1) {
        return true;
    }
```

This can be removed entirely, and dealt with in a rewritten `for` loop.

---

```
    for (int i = 0; num_to_parse; i++) {
        int point_end = num_to_parse - i - 1;
        if (inputString[i] == inputString[point_end]) {
            continue;
        } else if (i == num_to_parse) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The `for` loop's condition is never zero (it can't be once the suggestions are applied), this is just an infinite loop with a counter attached. The condition should be `i < num_to_parse`. That isn't what `for` loops are for. It just messes up everything (like your if statement does, it doesn't make sense). I'd rewrite the end of that function as (EDIT: improvements from comments):

```
    // (num_to_parse/2) means that i will reach the middle of the string, and no further.
    auto middleOfString = num_to_parse / 2;
    for (decltype(num_to_parse) i = 0; i < middleOfString; ++i) {
        if (inputString[i] != inputString[num_to_parse-i-1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Much more simple, and it [works](https://ideone.com/UU4wp1) :)

---

```
int main() {
    // Change the value of inputString to test different palindromes
    string inputString = "caabaac";
    printf("%s", is_palidrome(inputString)?"This is a palindrome.":"Not a palindrome."); // ternary: test condition ? return this if true : return this if false
    return 0;
}
```

The `printf` can be replaced with the C++ goodness and the ternary statement with a more readable (in this case) if/else statement.

---

With all this applied, the final code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool is_palidrome(std::string inputString) {
    auto num_to_parse = inputString.size();
    auto middleOfString = num_to_parse / 2;

    for (decltype(num_to_parse) i = 0; i < middleOfString; ++i) {
        if (inputString[i] != inputString[num_to_parse-i-1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}


int main() {
    // Change the value of inputString to test different palindromes
    std::string inputString = "caabaac";

    if (is_palidrome(inputString)) {
        std::cout << "This is a palindrome." << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Not a palindrome." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice first answer! I'm gonna pretend you stole all the things we both noticed from me, even though that's probably not true at all. :)

Comment: Thank you, thank you :) The truth is, I started writing this before you submitted it, so we both did these things ourselves :P But then the iffy `if` statement struck me, so I tested it and had to rewrite because OP's code didn't work.

Comment: @InternetAussie Yeah, it just happened in the coding environment I was using it did work, hence posting here, but I've since found it doesn't work in most others.

Comment: @RailsKiddie  tested it with some print-debugging, and we were getting negative array indices. NEGATIVE INDICES!

Comment: Yeah, I assumed as much -- that's pretty common here. Like I said, good answer! You might still be interested in [answer], if only so you can say you read it.

Comment: I can say I've read it now :D

Comment: I'm curious, why didn't you rewrite it using iterators rather than indexing? leftChar = inputString.begin() rightChar = inputString.end() while (leftchar != rightChar) { ... }

Comment: @pacmaninbw A few reasons: (1) More people are familiar and comfortable with indices, including myself. (2) There's not much benefit to using iterators. (3) If the string has an even length, the iterators will "cross over" and iterate over the entire string, rather than only half. (4) I have to remember to decrement the end iterator before starting, because it points to the element *after* the end.

Comment: I probably don't understand this properly, but won't performing the assignment and operation within the for loop result in slower code under some conditions?

Comment: @Incomputable surely it's fairly obvious that making an assignment and performing an operation *every single time* the loop executes, where it might have been performed once before the loop would result in increased load under most conceivable circumstances . I mean, am I being absurd here?

Comment: Interesting point. So we're talking about a problem that would only be applicable to single operation per cycle environments? Do you foresee any problems with taking the operation and assignment out of the `for` loop which might cause side-effects of some sort?

Comment: One minor improvement you can make:: if `num_to_parse` is 1, then `num_to_parse/2` is 0, so you could remove the check that `num_to_parse == 1` and change the loop condition to `i < num_to_parse/2`.  The middle letter of an odd-numbered string is always equal to itself and does not need to be checked. That way, when the length is 1, the program just falls through the loop.

Comment: @RailsKiddie Assignment and operation in the for loop result is constant, so a nice compiler will optimise it for you. And there won't be any side effects, because constant expression.

Comment: @Davislor That is true, making that adjustment now

Answer (score 15):

Ignoring issues of correctness and some of the other things that the other answers have gone into detail on, and instead focusing on simple program transformations (transforming the program into an equivalent program):

It is worth pointing out that whenever you have

```
if (c) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

you can just replace that with

```
return c;
```

Also, the `continue;` is unnecessary since there is nothing outside of those `if`s. You could make that `if` body empty (if you wanted to keep that structure). This would make it (note: I would not recommend actually *using* code with an empty `if` body, this is just a step in the larger transformation I'm suggesting):

```
if (inputString[i] == inputString[point_end]) {
} else {
  return i == num_to_parse;
}
```

From there, you could just change the loop to (fixing the conditional a bit, to what I suspect your intent was)

```
for (int i=0; i<num_to_parse; i++) {
  if (inputString[i] != inputString[point_end]) {
    return i == num_to_parse;
  }
}
```

This reveals an unnecessary computation, now the conditional in the `return` can never be `true`, because the loop will end before `i == num_to_parse`. Now this can be changed to:

```
for (int i=0; i<num_to_parse; i++) {
  if (inputString[i] != inputString[point_end]) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Again, this won't fix the issues of correctness since, other than my changing the conditional, none of the transformations changed the meaning of the program (as is usually the intent of program transformation). This was, however, addressed in the other answers.

This might better illuminate problems with correctness though, now that the code is simplified.

Also, on a somewhat unrelated subject: I'm not sure that I would describe this as "close to the metal." It definitely requires an operating system and it uses high-level constructs like `std::string`. This is not to say that it is bad, but I would not describe it as "close to the metal."

Comment: The only thing I don't agree with is the suggestion of eliding `continue` in favour of an empty body. `continue` is nice and explicit, an empty body looks like someone accidentally deleted something. I get that it's just a single step in a bigger transformation, but it would be good to make that clearer in case someone gets the wrong end of the stick and starts swapping their `continue`s for empty statements.

Comment: @Pharap Good point! I added a note about that.

Answer (score 12):

All other factors being equal, the best solution to a problem is the one that's easiest for someone else to understand.  You mention that you don't want to use anything but "basic loops and mathematical operations," but code that is easiest to understand usually *does not* contain raw, explicit loops.  Therefore I suggest the best solution is simply:

```
bool is_palindrome = std::equal(in.begin(), in.end(), in.rbegin());
```

Having a healthy understanding of [iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) is essential to writing concise algorithms using the standard library, so you owe it to yourself to make sure you're comfortable with them.  [`std::equal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) compares the elements of two ranges and returns `true` if the first element of each is equal, the second element of each is equal, etc. until the end is reached.  The [`rbegin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rbegin) and [`rend()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rend) functions of standard-library containers return reverse iterators over the container.  That is, iterators which traverse the container from the last element to the first instead of first to last.  So essentially what we're doing is checking if a reversed view of the string is equal to the string itself.

Of course, this does roughly twice as much work as is necessary, reading each character twice.  Unless you have extremely long strings, this is unlikely to matter at all, but if you want to reduce that linear-time coefficient in half anyway, you can do so without losing much readability:

```
bool is_palindrome = std::equal(in.begin(), in.begin() + (in.size() / 2), in.rbegin());
```

All the edge cases here just do the right thing, but I'll go over them anyway, just for laughs and kicks.

In the case of an empty string, `in.begin() == in.end()`, and `std::equal` returns `true` for empty ranges, so it is correctly considered a palindrome.  In the optimized version, `in.begin() + 0 == in.begin()` so we get the same thing.

In the case of a single character input, the first version compares it with itself, and (surprise!) finds that it's equal.  In the optimized version `in.size() / 2` becomes `1 / 2`, which when doing integer division, ends up as 0, so we're back to comparing an empty range, and it's considered a palindrome.

In the case of an input with odd length, the first version compares the character in the middle with itself, which is unnecessary but doesn't change the result.  In the optimized version, again `n / 2` truncates towards 0, so the middle character is ignored, and that's okay.

Since we know that the length counting from the beginning of the string is always going to be equal to the length if we start counting from the end of the string, we never need to worry about checking sizes explicitly or using the `std::equal` overload that takes an end iterator for the second range.

Finally, with a few modifications, you can make this algorithm truly generic, so that it will work on not only `std::string`, but also `std::wstring`, `char[N]` (though not string literals due to the null termination), `std::vector<int>`, etc.

```
template <typename T>
bool is_palindrome(const T& in) {
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    using std::rbegin;

    auto it1 = begin(in);
    auto it2 = it1 + (std::distance(it1, end(in)) / 2);
    return std::equal(it1, it2, rbegin(in));
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Your code has a bug in it when you pass in `string("")` or `string()`.  One other thing I’d like to point out is that your comment about how it saves time to check that `num_to_parse == 1` before entering the loop isn’t quite correct.  And you should always be wary when you find yourself writing a second check inside your loop that runs `continue`.  There’s a better way.

It’s never necessary to check the middle letter of an odd-length string, because it’s identical to itself.  So you can check `i < num_to_parse/2` and, when `num_to_parse` is 1, the program will immediately fall through the loop.

You do, however, need to check that the string size is not zero, or else you will initialize `point_end` to -1.  That makes `inputString[point_end]` a dangerous bug!

Here’s a fixed version.

```
bool is_palindrome2(const std::string& s)
{
  if (s.size() > 0) {
    const size_t last = s.size()-1;
    const size_t sentinel = s.size()/2;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sentinel; ++i )
      if (s[i] != s[last-i])
        return false;
  } // end if
  return true;  
}
```

Many programmers don’t like using unsigned indices that way; it might be safer to add an assertion that `last >= i`, just to be absolutely paranoid in case someone mucks up the loop..  In particular, Google would tell you to use signed types such as `ptrdiff_t` for loop indices and Microsoft to use `rsize_t`, so that you can catch underflow bugs more easily.

Since one of the commenters asked, why not use iterators, here’s a version that uses iterators.  On an architecture without machine-language indirect addressing, this might count as closer to the metal.  It’s also almost identical to the optimized code a C programmer would give you, and compiles to something just as fast:

```
bool is_palindrome1(const std::string& s)
{
  if (s.size() > 0) {
    std::string::const_iterator left = s.begin();
    std::string::const_iterator right = s.end()-1;

    while (left < right) {
      if (*left != *right)
        return false;

      ++left; // Often written: if (*left++ != *right--)
      --right;
    } // end while
  } // end if
  return true;  
}
```

And a test driver:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::size_t;

int main()
{
  const std::vector<std::string> testcases =
    { "", "a", "aa", "ba", "abccba", "abcdcba", "abdccba" };

  for ( const std::string& s : testcases )
    if ( is_palindrome2(s) && is_palindrome1(s) )
      cout << '\"' << s << "\" is a palindrome." << endl;
    else if ( !is_palindrome2(s) && !is_palindrome1(s) )
      cout << '\"' << s << "\" is not a palindrome." << endl;
    else
      cout << "Bug on input \"" << s << "\"." << endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Note sure about the "best" solution, but here's how I'd do it in C++:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool is_palindrome(const string &inputString)
{
    for(int i = 0, j = inputString.size() - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
        if (inputString[i] != inputString[j]) return false;
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <string>" << endl;
    else cout << "The string '" << argv[1] << "' is "
                << (is_palindrome(argv[1]) ? "" : "not ")
                << "a palindrome." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But since you mentioned close-to-the-metal, I endeavored to do it in C instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int is_palindrome(const char *inputString)
{
    int i, j;

    if (inputString)
        for(i = 0, j = strlen(inputString) - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
            if (inputString[i] != inputString[j]) return 0;
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) printf("Usage: %s <string>\n", argv[0]);
    else printf("The string '%s' is %sa palindrome.\n",
                argv[1], (is_palindrome(argv[1]) ? "" : "not "));
    return 0;
}
```

Note that in both cases, the loop conditional in `is_palindrome` also ensures that the empty string qualifies as a palindrome, without improperly attempting to access a character at index `-1`.

Comment: The C version needs a null pointer check.

Comment: Good point. Edited.

Comment: It isn't a correctness issue, but since this is a code review site, I must say that I would prefer to see more curly braces in your code. Even though I understand how it works, seeing a `for` loop immediately after an `if`, without the introduction of any scope, always makes me do I double-take. It also makes maintenance substantially more difficult.

Comment: That is a good point but I respectfully disagree. Over the decades (I've been writing code since the 1970s) I came to despise excessive curly braces. Beyond being (in my admittedly personal opinion) unnecessary pedantic, they also make the code harder to read, as it is spread out over more real estate, harder to see all at once. Yes, when there is a chance that there will be more code inserted, I use curly braces as well, or when there are too many levels of indentation. But when I judge that they can be omitted, I happily do so.

Comment: @ViktorToth Then at least put statements on different lines. That would allow you to put breakpoints on individual branches of `if`s.

Comment: @isanae: That's not necessary with a good debugger, which can place breakpoints on any full-expression no matter where in the line it appears.

Comment: @BenVoigt Not all of us have the privilege of working with such a unicorn :(

Comment: @BenVoigt Out of curiosity, which debugger do you know of that isn't line-based?

Comment: @isanae I usually put statements on separate lines, but I sometimes make exceptions for simple things like return or printing some text. I consider this a judgment call.

What irritates me more is the current prevailing practice of not putting opening curly braces on a separate line. This, in my (strictly personal) opinion affects readability and makes it that much harder to visually match opening and closing braces.

In the end, though, a lot of these things are subjective. When I work on a collaborative project, I just stay disciplined and follow the project's standards (if any).

Comment: @ViktorToth The fact that you find K&R difficult to read but like putting statements on the same line as an `if` makes no sense to me.

Comment: @isanae I developed/maintained 100,000+ line projects in C/C++ (and prior to that, Algol-60 and Simula-67). Based on that, I find that not putting an opening curly brace on its own line but insisting that `if (a>b) c=d;` must occupy two lines (or three, with curly braces!) makes little sense to me. (Note that I am not trying to pile arbitrary statements on the same line. These are simple conditionals.) But as I said, I realize these are subjective judgment calls. What I do with my own projects is my business. When I work collaboratively, I am disciplined and adhere to the group's standards.

Comment: @isanae FWIW it makes sense to me. `if(expression) statement;` is logical because it resembles a simple sentence. It's equally logical to ensure that brace pairs are vertically aligned. K&R's sytem of having the *start* brace at the *end* of a line and the *end* brace at the *start* of a line seems far more backwards by comparison.